# Many to many relationships in django; refering from one object to another

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

Ok guys, I got two different models:

```
class topic(models.Model):
        learningObjectivesTopic = models.ManyToManyField(learningObjective, verbose_name = "Lernziel")
        topic = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Thema')
```

and

```
class learningObjective(models.Model):
        learningObjectives = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Lernziel')
```

Pretty basic. My aim is to create entrys for the attribute "topic" and then refer to them when I want to create a new learning objective. My views obviously don't work the way I want them to work but I will post them to explain later on what my aim was.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from programm.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='login')
def lernziel(request):
        return render(request, 'lernziel.html', {'topic': topic.objects.all()})

@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_lernziel(request):
        neuesLernziel=learningObjective(learningObjectives=request.POST["Lernziel"])
        neuesLernziel.save()
        neuesLernziel_Topic=topic(topic=request.POST["Thema"])
        neuesLernziel_Topic.save()
        neuesLernziel_Topic.learningObjectivesTopic.add(neuesLernziel)
        return render(request, 'lernziel.html', {'topic': topic.objects.all()})

@login_required(login_url='login')
def themen(request):
        return render(request, 'themen.html', {'thema': topic.objects.all()})

@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_themen(request):
        neueThemen=topic(topic=request.POST['Thema'])
        neueThemen.save()
        return render(request, 'themen.html', {'thema': topic.objects.all()})
```

I thought with this line:

```
neuesLernziel_Topic.learningObjectivesTopic.add(neuesLernziel)
```

I could refer a learning objective, which I am about to create, to and existing topic. But how it seems, my django view just creates a new entry with a new id instead of using an old entry with the same value and an old id. To make it more clear: I have: topic1 and topic2. And I want to refer now 4 learning objectives. For instance lObj 1 and 3 to topic 1 and lObj 2 and 4 to topic 2. What happens is, that at the moment django created 4 new entrys in the topic table. It now contains 3 entrys with the value topic1 and 3 entrys with the value topic2. It should have been still 2 entrys and in the manytomany table it should use the odl id's. If you need more information or if something is unclear please write it :)

Btw I am receiving the data from these two templates:
**lernziel.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"de-de" }}" >
<head>
<h1 align = "center">Lernziele</h1>
</head>

<body>

<form action="{% url 'create_lernziel' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<br>Hallo Benutzer: {{ user.username }}</br>
Lernziel: <textarea name="Lernziel" rows="3" cols="45" ></textarea>
<p>
 <select name="Thema" size="3">
  {% for topic_ in topic %}
   <option>{{ topic_.topic }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
 </select>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Absenden" />
</form>

<table border="1">

<th>Lernziel</th>
<th>Thema</th>

{% for topic_ in topic %}
<tr>
{% for lObj in topic_.learningObjectivesTopic.all %}
<td>{{ lObj }}</td>
{% endfor %}
<td>{{ topic_.topic }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

and **themen.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<br>Hallo Benutzer: {{ user.username }}</br>

<form action="{% url 'create_themen' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<br>Thema: <textarea name="Thema" rows="3" cols="45"></textarea></br>
<input type="submit" value="Absenden" />
</form>

</br>
<table border="1">
<th>Thema</th>
{% for thema_ in thema %}
<tr>
<td>{{ thema_.topic }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with that line: it is with the previous two lines, which explicitly create a new Topic. If you want to associate your objective with an existing Topic, you need to use `get` to get it from the database, rather than instantiating a new one and calling `save()`.

```
neuesLernziel=learningObjective(learningObjectives=request.POST["Lernziel"])
neuesLernziel.save()
neuesLernziel_Topic = Topic.objects.get(topic=request.POST['Thema'])
neuesLernziel_Topic.learningObjectivesTopic.add(neuesLernziel)
```

You probably want to post/query by an ID, rather than the text of "topic", though.